# Mean or max pooling with masking support in Keras

Tags: python, masking, keras, lstm, pooling

```
...
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128))
model.add(LSTM(size, return_sequences=True, dropout_W=0.2 dropout_U=0.2)) 
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
....
```

I need to be able to take the mean or max of the vectors for all time steps in a sample after LSTM layer before giving this mean or max vector to the dense layer in Keras.

I think `timedistributedmerge` was able to do this but it was deprecated. Using `return_sequences=True` I can obtain the vectors for all time steps in a sample after the LSTM layer. However, `GlobalAveragePooling1D()` is not compatible with masking and it considers all time steps whereas I need only the non-masked time steps.

I saw posts recommending the `Lambda` layer but these also do not take masking into account. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Jacoxu's answer is right. But if you are using a tensorflow backend for keras, the Tensor type doesn't support dimshuffle function, try this instead.

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    if mask is not None:
        # mask (batch, time)
        mask = K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        # mask (batch, x_dim, time)
        mask = K.repeat(mask, x.shape[-1])
        # mask (batch, time, x_dim)
        mask = tf.transpose(mask, [0,2,1])
        x = x * mask
    return K.sum(x, axis=1) / K.sum(mask, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since average pooling is only doing a mean over one axis, you just need to correct the number of elements in the mean since loss masking is handled at the end, not here. You can do this probably with something like this:

```
class GlobalAveragePooling1DMasked(GlobalAveragePooling1D):
    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        if mask != None:
            return K.sum(x, axis=1) / K.sum(mask, axis=1)
        else:
            return super().call(x)
```

Comment: Note that you can't be certain in Keras that masked values in `x` are equal to zero! Therefore, this implementation would give wrong results.

Comment: The mask itself, introduced by the `Masking` and `Embedding` layer, is binary. Of course you can always have layers that implement `compute_mask` differently, but this is not happening in keras itself as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, the mask is binary. That is not what I'm saying :)

Comment: But that's the only assumption I make in the example above. I don't understand what you are getting at, sorry. Edit: Nevermind, it's the sum operation of matrix `x` that makes the assumption of masked values being zero. You are right. This *could* probably be fixed by indexing `x` by `mask` but I have to test this first.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the masked values in x be equal to zero, you can do this:

```
class MeanPool(Layer):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.supports_masking = True
    super(MeanPool, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
    # do not pass the mask to the next layers
    return None

def call(self, x, mask=None):
    if mask is not None:
        # mask (batch, time)
        mask = K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        # mask (batch, time, 'x')
        mask = mask.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x')
        # to make the masked values in x be equal to zero
        x = x * mask
    return K.sum(x, axis=1) / K.sum(mask, axis=1)

def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
    # remove temporal dimension
    return input_shape[0], input_shape[2]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it on Keras 2 (borrowing from all of the answers, and fixing the dimensions):

```
class MeanPool(Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.supports_masking = True
      super(MeanPool, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
      # do not pass the mask to the next layers
      return None

  def call(self, x, mask=None):
      if mask is not None:
          # mask (batch, time)
          mask = K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
          # mask (batch, x_dim, time)
          mask = K.repeat(mask, x.shape[-1])
          # mask (batch, time, x_dim)
          mask = tf.transpose(mask, [0,2,1])
          x = x * mask
      return K.sum(x, axis=1) / K.sum(mask, axis=1)

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
      # remove temporal dimension
      return (input_shape[0], input_shape[2])
```